# Color code geopandas plot by column value

Tags: geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe created with some open street map data.
Is there away to use the built in plot method to color code the dataframe based on the value of a specific column?

I.e. instead of

```
for color, group in gdf.groupby(['col']):
    plt.plot(group['X'], group['Y'], c=colors[color])
plt.show()
```

do something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(height, width))
gdf.plot("options_to_set for columns and colors", cmap = colors, figsize = (height, width), ax = ax)
```

?

Thanks for tips and help!

Comment: Can you provide more info about the dataframe and what you're hoping to see in the plot? there are lots of ways to plot colors and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done using `geoplot` library.

```
import geoplot as gplt
import geopandas as gpd

gplt.choropleth(gpd_df, hue='ex_gpd_df_col', projection=gplt.crs.PlateCarree())
```